# Competitions which have an entry fee halal?

Tags: halal-haram

There are different competitions which offer huge prizes but have some entry fee. It closely resemble lottery with an exception that you can only be rewarded after successful testing of your skill or knowledge. Are such competitions halal ?

Thanks

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].